# How do I change a shell scripts character encoding?

Tags: unix, shell, character-encoding

I am using [Gina Trapiani's excellent todo.sh](http://ginatrapani.github.com/todo.txt-cli/) to organize my todo-list.

However being a dane, it would be nice if the script accepted special danish characters like ø and æ.

I am an absolute UNIX-n00b, so it would be a great help if anybody could tell me how to fix this! :)

Comment: I've successfully used `todo.sh` with extended characters on Mac OS X..  Which platform are you using?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What does this command show?

```
locale
```

It should show something like this for you:

```
LC_CTYPE="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If not, you might try doing this before you run your script:

```
LANG=da_DK.UTF-8
```

You don't say what happens when you run the script and it encounters these characters. Are they in the todo file? Are they entered at a prompt? Is there an error message? Is something output in place of the expected output?

Try this and see what you get:

```
read -p "Enter some characters" string
echo "$string"
```

Answer (score 22):

Slowly, the Unix world is moving from ASCII and other regional encodings to UTF-8.  You need to be running a UTF terminal, such as a modern xterm or putty.

In your ~/.bash_profile set you language to be one of the UTF-8 variants.

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
or
export LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
etc..
```

You should then be able to write UTF-8 characters in the terminal, and include them in bash scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "UTF-8 is græat ☺"
```

See  also: https://serverfault.com/questions/11015/utf-8-and-shell-scripts

Comment: On a TTY (not xterm), the terminal might not be UTF-8 capable until `unicode_start` is run.  (This is unrelated to locale and shell/application support.)  Some distributions enable this at boot, but some don't.

Comment: Unrelated to OP's question, but posting just for the record. This fixed the issue I had when debugging a Python script with ipdb. It was returning `*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u22f1' in position 314: ordinal not in range(12)` every time I tried to print a variable. I tried to set `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, but only by setting to `export LANG=C.UTF-8` that it worked.

Comment: I came here exactly for the `ipdb` problem, but while I'm able to correctly print this: `echo "UTF-8 is græat ☺"`, I'm still getting the `UnicodeEncodeError` in `ipdb` :(