# Error when printing a variable in ipdb: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u22f1' in position 314: ordinal not in range(12)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, ipdb

I was debugging a Python 3 script and every time I tried to print a variable, it gave me the following error:

```
ipdb> inputs
*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u22f1' in
  position 314: ordinal not in range(12)
```

I tried to set the default encoding to UTF-8 using `sys.setdefaultencoding()` and adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the script, but both didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `export LANG=C.UTF-8`

---

[@mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21968640/957997) explains that it happens because Python picks the encoding setting from the environment it's been initiated from. If it can't find a proper encoding, it falls back to its default, 'ascii'.

My solution was to change the `locale` as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2038809/957997). Thus, I tried to set `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and, to my surprise, it didn't work. However, when I tried another locale, **`export LANG=C.UTF-8`** as suggested by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2038803/957997), it worked.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `ipdb` and setting `LANG=C.UTF-8` correctly doesn't make any difference. I run my tests using this pre-command before `tox`:
`eval $( ./dockerfiles/local_env.sh ) tox -e ....`, as you can imiagine `local_env.sh` contains some values I need to set to run my tests, but the point is that it already contains the right ones and I verify it with `eval $( ./dockerfiles/local_env.sh ) env | grep LANG` which returns me `LANG=C.UTF-8`, so it should work when `ipdb` kicks in, but it doesn't.

Comment: And I want to add an additional thing: if I run this `os.environ.get('LANG')` while I'm inside the `ipdb` debugger, it prints `'C.UTF-8'`, so the value was correctly set.

Comment: @AndreaGrandi interesting, I don't know what might be happening. It did take a couple of tries until I found one that worked for me, maybe you should try with other `LANG`s as well, but I'm not sure if it's due to the same issue.